# Firebase Hosting mime type

Tags: firebase-hosting

Has anyone found a way to set the mime type returned in the Content-Type header when hosting a file using Firebase Hosting? The docs say they support some headers in their rules file but not the content-type and I tied it anyway but fails the 'firebase deploy' due to error 'hosting.headers[0].headers[0].key is not one of enum values'. Also, the file i need to serve cannot have an extension which makes things harder for firebase to auto discover the type of the file.

Comment: Did that json help?

Answer (score 11):

I tested this and it seems to work. Also for your second issue why not set an extension anyways but change it to the mimetype you need?

```
{
  "database": {
    "rules": "database.rules.json"
  },
  "hosting": {
    "public": "public",    
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ],
    "headers": [
      {
        "source": "**/*.@(datagz|memgz|mem|data)",
        "headers": [
          {
            "key": "Content-Type",
            "value": "application/octet-stream"
          }
        ]
      } 
    ]
  }
}
```