# Angular2 route to static txt file

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I am trying to verify an service which needs an .txt file in the root folder of my website but the problem is that I allready have an angular2 router route that gets all requests and its getting this one too:

> { path: ':tag', component: AppHomeShareComponent},

I need to get /file.txt separate from this router, how can I do that? I have been searching for a solution to route that specific path but cannot find one.

Looking forward for your help!

Comment: I don't understand the question or the problem. How is the `file.txt` related to routing?

Comment: Because for example domain.com/file.txt is getting routed with AppHomeShareComponent that is getting everything after domain.com/* and I want to show the file and not getting routed.

Comment: I don't get a single word. I think you should add some code that demonstrates what you're doing.

Comment: Ok please check https://pluus.co/ATriggerVerify.txt and see what happens, its strange because on localhost is shows the file. The website is hosted on firebase hosting.

Comment: I guess the problem is that the file is served with mime type `text/html` instead of `text/plain`. I guess your question is a dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37727745/firebase-hosting-mime-type

Comment: Ok thanks for this, it wasn't what I needed for my issue. Actually angular wasn't packing the txt file when was builded for production. Adding the file in angular-cli.json resolved my issue. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: Yes, forgot to add the static file inside angular-cli.json under apps > assets . It wasn't included on compile.

Answer (score -2):

This is not related to the routing but directly related to your Rewriting rule, you have to put an exception is the file exist.

In a ASP.NET application, it would be something like this:

```
<add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
<add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
```

In a Apache context, the rule exception would be:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
```